# Arrayfire - rendering a heatmap as an image/array with the available colormaps

Tags: c++, image-processing, simulation, heatmap, arrayfire

I'm using Arrayfire to make a 2D heat transfer simulation. My dataset is a matrix of temperatures and I want to vizualize it as a heatmap. I need to produce frames of the colored dataset and save it as an image on the disk. So each temperature in my dataset has to be mapped to a color according to a certain color scheme.

I found that you can render the dataset in a window with a colormap using fig():
http://blog.accelereyes.com/blog/2013/07/03/arrayfire-examples-part-7-of-8-pde/

I also found that the colormaps available:
http://arrayfire.org/docs/defines_8h.htm#a553ceda8a1d8946efac3b08e642574ae

My plan so far has been to render the colored dataset using window.image() in a hidden window and then extract an array/image from the result so I can save this result using saveImage(). But I cannot find a way to extract the image rendered by the window.

Is there a better way to do this using the image processing functions? I would like to avoid defining my own color scheme. (i.e. making my own function that maps a temperature to a color)

Comment: The blog you are referring to uses ArrayFire v2.* and ArrayFire has changed a lot since we went v3.0

As of now, there is no way to create hidden windows. As you already figured out, we can render an array as colormap in a window. 

As you know, we can write a mapping function using ArrayFire JIT and lookup/indexing functions. It should give almost close to native kernel performance - in fact scenarios such as these are good use cases for JIT.

Have you tried bench-marking it ? Please share the code you tried and we will suggest improvements if any possible.